# LAMP and memory/swap space problem

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks, imagemagick

My LAMP application seems to eventually use up all of my server's memory and swap space. My gut feeling is that it has something to do with the external processes I have to call (as that is the only time the problem manifests).

I need to call GhostScript, ImageMagick's "convert", PDFTK, etc. constantly. When those processes are running, that's when I see my memory running out. So, questions:

1. Which techniques should I use to conclusively identify which process is actually causing the memory problems? My plan right now is to run the processes individually and just observe the memory usage via the *nix command "top". Is there a way I can do this programatically?
2. Is there any "memory flushing" solutions I can use? Would this be a good idea to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another problem you might face is the fact that when forking, the application where you fork from is "doubled" so its memory consumption doubles. If you have a app server which is resident and keeps a lot of data cached this can be very significant.

A solution to this problem is to run a small resident script/program listening on a socket or named pipe to launch the external programs.

You can use `top -b` (or similar) to receive computer readable output and monitor the memory consumption there with a script.

BTW: Do not count swap space as "real" memory, your app should run without ever hitting swap space. Once you start hitting swap space performance goes down so fast that request start piling up, causing more memory to be used, causing more stuff to be swapped. If you see significant swap space being allocated then increase memory (or buy a bigger hosting plan)

Comment: These external processes are called via PHP's exec(). Does that constitute forking? Shouldn't these processes release memory when they are done? Or am I supposed to do it somehow? How do I find out if they are not releasing memory?

Comment: Yes, php exec uses fork to create the subprocess. It will release the memory when the application is done, as long as you have not redirected input/output files which are blocked for one reason or another.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your comment, "A solution to this problem is to run a small resident script/program listening on a socket or named pipe to launch the external programs."?

Comment: When a process forks on a UNIX host, it creates a copy of the program data space. An app server typically has a huge data space, and a small script a tiny one. So it is cheaper to fork a process from a small program talking to the app server using some kind of inter-process communication, e.g. sockets, named pipes or some IPC queue.